# Center last element of a container in the middle of container

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I'm trying to create some sort of "slide menu" where all the items are shown, and the current item is standing out.

The issue I have right now is that when an item is selected, it does not scroll to the center of the container.

[image: Example]

To solve that issue, I added a wrapper element between the items and the container and sets the width to be extremely large, then with JavaScript scroll to the current item.

Is there a way to achieve the same result without doing this workaround?

*CSS:*

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%; 
}

.wrapper.hard {
  width: 10000000px;
}

.item_wrapper {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box, .box2 {
  height: 80%;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: cyan;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.box.current, .box2.current {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Dynacord/sz3daL46/

Comment: Are you okay to use a plugin for this? If yes, you can use Slick slider and check for its Center Mode in https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: @AKNair Unfortunately, no I am not. Checked slick out of curiosity but the center mode loops around, which is something that I don't want. Going to edit the post and remove mentionning a carousel as this might be confusing

Comment: If looping the issue with Slick, you have a setting in Slick slider to control it. Just set "infinite: false" and it will give you desired result.